# How do you use variables within $_POST?

Tags: php, variables, post

How do you use variables within $_POST? I've tried using $_POST[$row['Field']]; I've tried assigning this to a variable to see if it works and then echoing the value but nothing is displayed.

Comment: Very basic stuff.. 1 second google: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Comment: I've tried searching on google and I've tried many different methods but they do not seem to work for me as I'm using an array variable. I've also used $_POST[$row['myfield']]; 
$_POST["{$row['myfield']}"]; 
$_POST["$row[myfield]"];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$_POST is an associative array that is set by forms using the "method=post" attribute.  You can access it like the following:

Lets say you have the form:

```
<form action="" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="first_name" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

You would access the "first_name" input box using the following variable:

```
$_POST['first_name']
```

If "row" is an array that you have made (for example: $row = array('Field' => 'first_name');):

```
$_POST[$row['Field']];
```

Notice that since "row" is a PHP array, you must have the "$" before it.

If using $row doesn't give you the right result, you can do:

```
die(print_r($row,true));
```

To see what "$row" is currently set to.  Check to make sure that $row is correct, then do a:

```
die(print_r($_POST,true));
```

To see if your $_POST variables are set correctly.

Comment: Thanks, I think it actually ended up being that my POST values were incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if the index of `$_POST` exists, something like this :

```
$myVar = (isset($row['Field']) && isset($_POST[$row['Field']]))?$_POST[$row['Field']]:false;
var_dump($myVar);
```

If this code print `false`, then one of your var has a problem.